# How to Construct an asynchronously executed task chain based on Java CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I have N tasks to execute, and the number of tasks is not fixed. The next task can only be executed after the previous task is completed. How can the entire task chain be executed asynchronously?

If the number of tasks is fixed, such as N=2, I can use the following code. How to do it if N is not fixed

```
public void futureTest() throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> finalFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        CompletableFuture<Integer> cf1 = doTask(1);
        AtomicReference<CompletableFuture<Integer>> cf2 = new AtomicReference<>(new CompletableFuture<>());

        cf1.whenComplete(((integer1, throwable1) -> {
            if (throwable1 != null) {
                finalFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable1);
                return;
            }
            
            // when task1 complete then submit task2
            cf2.set(doTask(2));
            cf2.get().whenComplete(((integer2, throwable2) -> {
                if (throwable2 != null) {
                    finalFuture.completeExceptionally(throwable2);
                    return;
                }
                
                finalFuture.complete(integer2);
            }));
        }));
        
        finalFuture.whenComplete(((integer, throwable) -> {
            System.out.println("all task is done");
        }));
        
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    }

private CompletableFuture<Integer> doTask(int index) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();

        // Simulate task execution
        THREAD_POOL.execute(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(3_000);
            cf.complete(index);
        });
        
        return cf;
    }
```

I looked at Compeltable's API docs and none of them seem to solve my problem. I tried to use a loop to control the task submission, but all failed, unable to submit the next task after the previous task is completed

Comment: How do you know, how many task you have? Or will you invoke `doTask` up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer on this thread [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69857335). Seems a duplicate of this question.

**thenRun** method is used to run the task after the previous future is completed successfully. This method will be skipped in case of any failures in previous stages.

**whenComplete** method is used as the final stage of execution chain. Here you will receive the composed result of all the other functions in the supply chain and you can choose to fail your future or handle exceptions accordingly inside this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose the futures for the individual tasks via [`CompletableFuture#thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) in a loop:

```
CompletableFuture<?> future = createFirstTask();
while (hasMoreTasks()) {
    future = future.thenCompose(this::createNextTask);
}
```

Here every next tasks depends on the result of the previous one until no more task is left.

Conceptionally this is a fold operation, which unfortunately is not part of the API of `CompletableFuture`. But if you don't mind using my [better future library](https://github.com/mduerig/better-future) (which is just a thin wrapper around `CompleteableFuture`), I just recently added support for [folding streams of futures](https://github.com/mduerig/better-future#combining-reducing-folding-and-collecting) there.